# NGINX Unit + Flask = not found among the available application modules

Tags: python, flask, nginx-unit

this is happens when i upload config.json:

```
sudo curl -X PUT --data-binary @config.json --unix-socket /var/run/control.unit.sock http://localhost/config
{
        "error": "Invalid configuration.",
        "detail": "The module to run \"python 3.6\" is not found among the available application modules."
}
```

i tried: `Python`, `Python 3.7`

my config.json that i trying to upload:

```
    {
  "listeners": {
    "*:1234": {
      "pass": "applications/flask"
    }
  },
  "applications": {
    "flask": {
      "type": "python 3.6",
      "processes": 5,
      "path": "/home/123/123/",
      "home": "/home/123/123/venv/",
      "module": "wsgi",
      "user": "root",
      "group": "root"
    }
  }
}
```

This is all happens when i trying to make simple flask-demo with nginx unit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you should check if the python module is properly installed. In order to discover where they are located, you can use the `unitd --help` as it shows the default options.

```
$ unitd --help
...

  --modules DIRECTORY  set modules directory name
                       default: "/usr/lib/unit/modules"
```

*If you use a custom systemd unit or script, you should check the option --modules*

Simply list the files in the modules directory:

```
$ ls /usr/lib/unit/modules
python3.6.unit.so  python3.7.unit.so
```

If they are there, check in the beginning of the unit.log if they were correctly loaded:

```
$ sudo more /var/log/unit.log 
2020/04/29 22:24:47 [info] 13025#13025 discovery started
2020/04/29 22:24:47 [notice] 13025#13025 module: python 3.6.9 "/usr/lib/unit/modules/python3.6.unit.so"
2020/04/29 22:24:47 [notice] 13025#13025 module: python 3.7.5 "/usr/lib/unit/modules/python3.7.unit.so"
2020/04/29 22:24:47 [notice] 13024#13024 process 13025 exited with code 0
2020/04/29 22:24:47 [info] 13027#13027 router started
2020/04/29 22:24:47 [info] 13026#13026 controller started
2020/04/29 22:24:47 [info] 13027#13027 OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018, 1010100f
```

If they were not loaded, the log will say the reason.
*Unit module versions must match the Unit version installed*. If you installed a newer version in a system running the old version, you should reinstall the unit modules as well (`apt install unit-dev unit-python3.6 unit-python3.7`).

Comment: thanks, i have an error:

[notice] 107011#107011 no modules matching: "/usr/lib/unit/modules/*.unit.so" found

Comment: and is the modules there? How did you install the python modules?

Comment: Ok, Unit was installed before the python modules. That's why,

Comment: yes modules there, i just follow instruction on https://unit.nginx.org/howto/flask/ but looks like make a mistake

Comment: The module type string must be exactly matched in the log. Like `python 3.6.9 ` (see the log above) instead of `python 3.6`